# Plugin Options Page and Subpage

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I'm working on a plugin which it's options need to be managed by admins and super admins [yes, it's a network site]. the idea is that super users can create `resources` which are then enabled by the regular admins.

So I created a Menu Item with two subpages. well just one subpage which will have the `resources` configuration option page.

My question is if I should be storing the options in two different fields meaning in wp_options, I have two entries, or can I utilize a single one.

Currently I have a single entry 'my_plugin_settings'. 
Do I need to make two? 'my_plugin_admin_settings' & 'my_plugin_superadmin_settigns'

???

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple options pages for plugin, ensure that your sanitize function gets the additional missing options from the database

example

```
public function sanitize($input): array
{
  /** My Plugin Setting Options */
  $option = get_option('my_plugin_settings');
  /** Do this for all the settings keys in your options array */
  if ($input['setting_key']) {
    $output['setting_key'] = $input['setting_key'];
  } else {
    $output['setting_key'] = $option['setting_key'];
  }

  return $output;
}
```